# Brute force access to a Firebird database?

Tags: password, mysql

Ok, so here's the deal. When migrating a certain product with terrible documentation to another database type, my Firebird database was deleted. I then proceeded to recover it from the filesystem using a recovery tool. Now, I need to get into it to be able to dump the data and transfer it to MySQL, the new database.

The problem is that the company who makes the software won't give me the username and password to the Firebird database so I can migrate it. The client is justifiably upset as we've had downtime for over a week on this service.

What can I use to get the username and password for the database?

Comment: Firebird's open source?

Comment: Yes, Firebird is open source. It's the least-known out of Firebird, SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default username/password combination is SYSDBA:masterkey

See also [I forgot my Firebird server password, how to get it back?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq55/), which advises replacing `security.fdb` with one from a different database with known credentials.

There's also the general [getting help](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/qsg25-gettinghelp.html) page which links to mailing lists.